# Die, [multiple], die! *stabstabstab*

Tags: support, tags

I've just noticed this tag float across (as the only tag on a question, which was what brought it to my attention).  I've skimmed over the list of questions with the tag (66 at current count), and I can't find a single one for which the tag seems to fit.

Would a mod like to exercise their super-cow powers to make this tag unused without causing undue distress to the front page, with a view to blacklisting it down the road?

Comment: I'll take a look...

Comment: Yeah, that's a meta-tag. We don't like thems 'round here. And looks like no one was silly enough to put it as the only tag on something.

Comment: They were, it's why I found it.  I retagged the question in question (http://serverfault.com/posts/293255/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

Poot. They fixed that method. Will need a Super-Unicorn for this one, I'm afraid. A Dev can outright remove tags, Mods can't. We can merge them into something else. Once upon a time you could merge into a blank field which had the effect of removing a tag, but, ahm, they fixed that input validation. Happily, I know where to find devs.

Comment: I believe that tags without questions are automagically deleted. This doesn't stop someone else from recreating the tag though.

Comment: They need to add a field to the DB of blackholed tags. Part of the problem right now is that it's an RE search, so they don't let anyone add something as a misplaced `.*` would take out the whole site.